# Alpha Volume Scatter Weirdness

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, node-editor, transparency, volumetrics

I have a volume scatter box (which is fog) which has a principled volume shader on it. I then have this barrel with a png image in front of it, i enabled the alpha... however the volume scatter box is creating this weird line on it.

If i remove the volume scatter box it goes away. Not sure how to fix. Help!

I saw this old post that talks about it but the solution is very unclear.
RIGHT HERE
[Alpha Transparency Lightening and Volume Scatter](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/76346/alpha-transparency-lightening-and-volume-scatter)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok i figured it out. Literally, just add 1 to the Min Transparent bounces and fixed.

[image]